# using of inversion in english

Tags: grammar

Only when **is the green light on** vehicles may cross the train track.

Only when **the green light is on** vehicles may cross the train track.

which of these is grammatically correct to use, as I have learnt the word **only** at the beginning of the sentence followed by auxiliary verb(inversion), but it sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: I've delted my answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The inversion required is of *vehicles* and *may*:

Only when the green light is on **may vehicles** cross the train track.